# Replacing postgres stored procedure in php

Tags: php, database, postgresql, cockroachdb

I'm faced with the task of running a third party software with `cockroachdb` instead of the supported `postgresql`. I naively thought it would be a simple conversion as `cockroachdb` is a `superset` of postgresql. However as I work on the conversion I realised `cockroachdb` does not support `Stored Procedures` and `Triggers`. There is a `functions.sql` file that contains the `Stored Procedures` while there are various php files that call the SQL functions. Since `cockroachdb` doesn't support stored procedures my idea is to create php functions that mimic the stored procedure in the SQL file. This is the only workaround I can think of but my knowledge in php is close to none so your expertise would be helpful. I'm assuming this can be done based on my knowledge with python where I can use pyscopg2 library or an ORM like SQLAlchemy.

Below is one of the stored procedures:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_format(
    timestamp without time zone, 
    text) 
    RETURNS text AS $$ 
    DECLARE 
    i int := 1; temp 
    text := ''; 
    c text; 
    n text; 
    res text; 
BEGIN 
    WHILE i <= pg_catalog.length($2) 
    LOOP c := SUBSTRING ($2 FROM i FOR 1); 
        IF c = '%' AND i != pg_catalog.length($2) THEN n := SUBSTRING ($2 FROM (i + 1) FOR 1); 
        SELECT INTO res CASE 
            WHEN n = 'a' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'Dy') 
            WHEN n = 'b' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'Mon') 
            WHEN n = 'c' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMMM') 
            WHEN n = 'D' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMDDth') 
            WHEN n = 'd' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'DD') 
            WHEN n = 'e' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMDD') 
            WHEN n = 'f' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'US') 
            WHEN n = 'H' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'HH24') 
            WHEN n = 'h' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'HH12') 
            WHEN n = 'I' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'HH12') 
            WHEN n = 'i' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'MI') 
            WHEN n = 'j' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'DDD') 
            WHEN n = 'k' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMHH24') 
            WHEN n = 'l' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMHH12') 
            WHEN n = 'M' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMMonth') 
            WHEN n = 'm' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'MM') 
            WHEN n = 'p' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'AM') 
            WHEN n = 'r' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'HH12:MI:SS AM') 
            WHEN n = 'S' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'SS') 
            WHEN n = 's' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'SS') 
            WHEN n = 'T' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'HH24:MI:SS') 
            WHEN n = 'U' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '?') 
            WHEN n = 'u' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '?') 
            WHEN n = 'V' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '?') 
            WHEN n = 'v' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '?') 
            WHEN n = 'W' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'FMDay') 
            WHEN n = 'w' THEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM $1)::text 
            WHEN n = 'X' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '?') 
            WHEN n = 'x' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '?') 
            WHEN n = 'Y' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'YYYY') 
            WHEN n = 'y' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, 'YY') 
            WHEN n = '%' THEN pg_catalog.to_char($1, '%') 
        ELSE NULL END; temp := temp operator(pg_catalog.||) res; i := i + 2; 
        ELSE temp = temp operator(pg_catalog.||) c; i := i + 1; 
        END IF; 
    END LOOP; 
RETURN temp; 
END $$ IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And one of the php files calls the procedure like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT date_format(c.date_commande,'%m') as dm, SUM(c.".$this->field.")";
```

Is my proposed work around too naive? Is there a better way to approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach with PHP seems reasonable granted I don't development in PHP.

However, it may be easier to use the CockroachDB builtin `experimental_strftime`.

See here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.1/functions-and-operators#date-and-time-functions